# How do I enable USB debugging on an android phone with an unresponsive screen?

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen, samsung-galaxy-j5

I have a Samsung Galaxy J5 2017 with a broken screen,
the screen is black and unresponsive.

I found an app that I can use to mirror my phone screen to my PC so I can recover my Google Authenticator codes for my accounts which requires USB debugging to be enabled. Unfortunately I don't have USB debugging enabled on this phone, I found a few ways to enable USB debugging but none of them work for me.

I can't use an external keyboard / mouse or go into recovery mode because the screen is black. I also can't use the screenshotting method because the screen is unresponsive.

Is there a way to enable USB debugging using my PC?

Comment: On devices I know screen shots are created using hardware keys, so that should work no matter if the screen shows something or the touch digitizer works at all. For the other methods you will not be able to avoid to use your phone blind without screen (e.g. using a connected keyboard).

Comment: Hi, @Robert. I know how screenshots are created, but like I said the phone is unresponsive which means the touch screen does not work. I know I can connect a mouse to the phone but I need a way to do it from my PC.

Comment: I doubt it as it would violate the basic security. I  am not convinced that this phone is yours

Comment: LMAO. The phone is mine, I accidently dropped it and the screen broke. I am getting a new phone so I didn't want to waste money on replacing the screen but I needed my 2FA codes to log in to my social accounts on my new phone. I ended up getting the screen replaced though.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot enable USB debugging from a PC.It would be a major security flaw if anyone with a PC could simply enable USB debugging on any android device they decide to plug in.

Comment: Figured it out already, thanks anyway though.